# Use numba with dask dataframe

Tags: dask, numba

I have a dataframe that contains a string and 3 other columns that are numpy arrays, and I do the following:

```
def calculate_hash_chunk(chunk, modalities):
    num_modalities = len(modalities)
    
    def _calculate_hash(chunk):
        if num_modalities == 1:
            return chunk[modalities[0]]
        if num_modalities == 2:
            hash_0 = chunk[modalities[0]]
            hash_1 = chunk[modalities[1]]
            return np.bitwise_xor(hash_0, hash_1)
        if num_modalities == 3:
            hash_0 = chunk[modalities[0]]
            hash_1 = chunk[modalities[1]]
            hash_2 = chunk[modalities[2]]
            return np.bitwise_and(
                        np.bitwise_xor(hash_0, hash_1),
                        np.bitwise_xor(hash_0, hash_2),
                        np.bitwise_xor(hash_1, hash_2))
    return chunk.assign(hash_result=chunk.apply(_calculate_hash, axis=1))


def calculate_hash_df(df, modalities, meta):
    hash_result = {"hash_result": object}
    meta.update(hash_result)
    return df.map_partitions(lambda partition: calculate_hash_chunk(partition, modalities), meta=meta)
```

This performs as expected, however, when I'm trying to use numba njit decorator, the following happens:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
non-precise type pyobject
During: typing of argument at /tmp/ipykernel_20351/1214465196.py (5)

File "../../../../tmp/ipykernel_20351/1214465196.py", line 5:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?> 

This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 0: Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

That is explaining that numba can not operate with Series. However, is any way to do this so I can increase the performance and have the best of both worlds?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your `df` gets partitioned into a Series object, which gets passed to the Numba function. But Numba won't work with such high level objects. You should probably decorate a lower level function, like the one passed to `apply()`. See the Pandas documentation for some examples on how to use Numba:  
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#numba-jit-compilation

Comment: To be sure: it's the `_calculate_hash` that you want to decorate with JIT? Does it work with pandas (not dask) on part of the data? Have you tried defining the function standalone rather than dynamic?

Answer (score -2):

numba only operates on numpy arrays. If a pandas.Series is backed by numpy (as opposed to pyArrow), you can do this:

```py
def external(s: pandas.Series):
    # If internal reduces to scalar
    return internal(s.values)
    # If internal is a 1:1 map
    return pandas.Series(internal(s.values), index=s.index, name=s.name)

@njit
def internal(a: numpy.ndarray) -> numpy.ndarray:
    ...
```